# Spark hangs when I connect to Cassandra with repartitionByCassandraReplicator

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

Whenever I try to query my cassandra db like this:

```
sc.parallelize(keys).repartitionByCassandraReplica("keyspace","mytable")
      .joinWithCassandraTable("keyspace", "mytable")
      .select("whatever")
```

my spark job will hang indefinitely on this line in the logs:

```
INFO CassandraConnector: Disconnected from Cassandra cluster: mycluster
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was somehow caused by the fact that I was running cassandra through CCM. When I installed and ran cassandra directly, the problem went away.